# SQL: How to connect a foreign key to primary key in the some table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ERD and I need to connect the foreign key to the primary key on the same table. I have tried the below SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE Category(
    CategoryID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
        CONSTRAINT cat_cid_pk PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    CategoryName VARCHAR(100) 
        CONSTRAINT cat_can_nn NOT NULL,
    ParentCategoryID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
        CONSTRAINT cat_pcid_fk REFERENCES SWD6_1B.[Category]([CategoryID]);
)
```

And below I have the ERD

[image: ERD Table]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Category(

CategoryID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT cat_cid_pk PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),

CategoryName VARCHAR(100) CONSTRAINT cat_can_nn NOT NULL,
ParentCategoryID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
CONSTRAINT cat_pcid_fk foreign key (ParentCategoryID) REFERENCES [Category]([CategoryID])
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the table and then use `alter table`:

```
alter table Category add constraint cat_pcid_fk
    foreign key (ParentCategoryID) references SWD6_1B.[Category]([CategoryID]);
```